# Pass curried function result as parameter in C++

Tags: c++, std-function

**Background**

 I'm trying to pass a `std::function` object as a parameter to `evaluate` the sum of its returned value over a range.


 However, for some reason, the function depends on a functor, `Bar`, whose state depends on a parameter, `a`.


 My approach was to create a `lambda` inside a curried function, `foo` and ask it to capture a functor allocated by `new`.

 However, I found that after I passed the function created by `foo` into `evaluate` the address of the functor changed and the program did some crazy things.


 **Example**

 Here's a simplified reproducible example,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

double evaluate(const function<double (const double &)> foo) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (double i=0; i<1; ++i) {
        result += foo(i);
    }
    return result;
}

struct Bar {
    double a;

    explicit Bar(const double &a): a(a) {}

    double operator()(const double &b) const {
        return b * a;
    }
};

function<double(const double &)> foo(const double &a) {
    auto bar = new Bar(a);
    function<double (const double &)> result = [&](const double &b) {
        cout << "address of bar: " << bar << endl;
        return (*bar)(b);
    };
    return result;
}



int main() {
    auto f = foo(1);
    auto v = f(2);
    cout << "value of f(2): " << v << endl;

    v  = evaluate(f);
    cout << "evaluate(f): " << v << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A possible output of the above code could be

```
address of bar: 0x7ff7b787c870
value of f(2): 4.3834e-314
address of bar: 0x7ff7b787c840
evaluate(f): 0
```

**Questions**

 Can anyone

- explain why the address of the functor changed;
- provide other better ways of doing this? (assume I cannot directly pass the functor to the `evaluate` function)

Comment: Is `i<1` really `i<one`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I iterated only for `i=0` for the purpose of illustration

Comment: *"assume I cannot directly pass the functor to the `evaluate` function"* -- which functor is "the" functor? Asking because you do pass a functor to `evaluate`, namely `f` (a `std::function` object).

Comment: *"allocated by `new`."* -- if you're going to allocate something, you need to also de-allocate it. I see your `new`; where is your `delete`? Why not use a smart pointer, so you don't have to explicitly de-allocate?

Comment: BTW, `double` can be passed by value instead of const reference.

Comment: You can just capture `bar` by value (saving the pointer) instead of by reference (which saves a reference to a local variable containing the pointer), when defining the lambda. Replace [&] by [=] or by [=bar].

Comment: @Jarod42 In a simplified example, I'm inclined to think `double` could be a stand-in for a more complex type. Which is good, and not really something to nitpick over when it is tangential to the question, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in UB world. Because `bar` is a local variable here which is captured by **reference**:

```
function<double(const double &)> foo(const double &a) {
    auto bar = new Bar(a);
    function<double (const double &)> result = [&](const double &b) {
        cout << "address of bar: " << bar << endl;
        return (*bar)(b);
    };
    return result;
}
```

And you want to access it in other places assuming it exists. You should have already noticed a problem in your code from this result:

```
value of f(2): 4.3834e-314
```

Because it should be `2`. If you write code as follows:

```
function<double(const double &)> foo(const double &a) {
    function<double (const double &)> result = [bar = new Bar(a)](const double &b) {
        cout << "address of bar: " << bar << endl;
        return (*bar)(b);
    };
    return result;
}
```

It will work as you expect. Just remember to use `std::unique_ptr` rather than raw pointer here. This code, as it is right now, has a memory leak as a result of forgetting to release memory.

Comment: You might remove `new` to avoid the memleak too (and so replace `(*bar)` by `bar`).

Comment: @Jarod42 I mentioned it is better to use `std::unique_ptr`, but I didn't change original code in this specific place because I wanted to show that main problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Afshin Got it, thanks! So, after we exit `foo`, the bar captured by reference will be destroyed but that `Bar` in that the address still exists?

Comment: @MaxWong Yes. `Bar` instance that is allocated by `new` exists, but you have its address in `bar` variable which will be destroyed after exiting `foo` and you practically keeping an address to `bar` in your lambda since your capture is `&`. As a result, when you try to access your allocated `Bar` via an already destroyed variable `bar` address, it is UB.